# How to copy one column's value to another before updating

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am runnning a Postgres and Mysql server and I have table:

```
  id   | name | age | old_age
  1       abc    20
```

I want to update column age with 21 with storing old value 20 into old_age column.
I can fetch the row and read the value of age and then update but that will require running 2 queries. 1 select and 1 update. Is there any way we can update in 1 query? I just want to copy age to old_age.

Comment: That is actually not the way to go. Store the date of birth and calculate the age on-the-fly when needed

Comment: ...assuming the entity in question is 'born'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
UPDATE TableName SET old_age=age, age=21 WHERE
```